# Defining precision for EntityFramework function import parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure with `decimal(38,6)` parameter. I imported this function into my EF model (Db first). As I checked the generated `CSDL content`, I found this :

```
  <FunctionImport Name="sp_blob" ReturnType="Collection(Model1.sp_blob_Result)">
    ...
    <Parameter Name="Price" Mode="In" Type="Decimal" />
  </FunctionImport>
```

When I call this function through EF , it raises `Parameter value '1000000000000.00' is out of range.` error with 1000000000000.00 value.

I tried to change the parameter precision by EF Designer but nothing found for this! So I changed the CSDL content directly to :

```
<Parameter Name="Price" Mode="In" Type="Decimal" Precision="36" Scale="2" />
```

Unfortunately these changes are removed after any "Update Model from Database" in designer. What should I do? Any workaround?

P.S. : Visual Studio is 2013 Update 3 + EF 6.1.1

Comment: Could it have something to do with Type="Decimal"? (value=1000000000000.00)

Comment: I don't get your point  but the related SP works with this value correctly. Also .net decimal type accepts this value without any problem/correction/rounding